# Updatable theme developing

Tags: theme-development, updates, upgrade

I made a wordpress theme and I want to sell it and support the theme for a time so I need update the theme.However I dont know how to do it? Also I wonder if I make new version as full theme, Will costumers lose anything from their theme customization or not? If I edit only some part of the theme, can I prepare a new version with only that parts instead of make it with new full theme? How can I do these features?

Comment: If users modify your theme's code, they should use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). That way they can accept theme updates without creating code conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, Also I wonder customization that you know changing color or theme settings like redux framework, will all of them save?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that a theme update shouldn't overwrite theme settings saved in the database.

Comment: so how can I update my theme?

Comment: [If you're distributing via WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/themes/upload/): "If you are uploading a theme update, simply increase the version inside of style.css and upload the theme-name.zip file again, just like you do with a new theme."